# WPF how to manage ENTER hit on TextBox for messaging purpose

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, keydown

Take a simple messaging program, such as Steam friend conversation.

When you hit `ENTER`, the message is **sent**, and the message field is **emptied**.

When you enter `CTRL/SHIFT + ENTER` **a newline is created**. If your cursor is not at the end of the input text, **then all the text appearing after your cursor will be sent to a newline**.

Well, how do you accomplish such a feat ?

Furthermore, I'd like to know how to have the aforementioned features and also how to still be able to paste a multiline text into the message field.

For now, this is my code. It's something but does not get all the job done :

```
private bool ctrlOrShift = false;
private void MessageField_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
{
    if( e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || e.Key == Key.LeftShift )
    {
        ctrlOrShift = true;
    }

    else if( e.Key == Key.Enter && ctrlOrShift != true && !MessageField.AcceptsReturn )
    {  
         AsyncSendMessage();
    }
    else if( e.Key == Key.Enter && ctrlOrShift != true && MessageField.AcceptsReturn )
    {
         MessageField.AcceptsReturn = false;
    }
    else if( e.Key == Key.Enter && ctrlOrShift == true )
    {
         ctrlOrShift = false;
         MessageField.AcceptsReturn = true;
         MessageField.Text += System.Environment.NewLine;
         MessageField.Select( MessageField.Text.Length, 0 );
         MessageField.AcceptsReturn = false;
    }
    else
    {
         ctrlOrShift = false; // Canceled because follow-up key wat not ENTER !
    }
}
```

The following scenarios occur :

1. Using `CTR` or `SHIFT`, I can create a new line in my `TextBox` :) ;
2. I cannot paste a multiline text from the `Clipboard`: only the first line will be pasted, nothing else :( ;
3. If I use `CTRL + V` to paste content, the `MessageField_KeyDown` event takes the `CTRL` hit is taken into account, therefore, if I press `ENTER`, message is not sent but a newline is created instead :/ (in a case where you would paste a content and send it right away) ;
4. If my cursor position is before the end of the input text, `CTR/SHIT + ENTER` will create a newline at the end of the text regardless of the cursor position :/

So, how can I tweak this code ? Thanks for the help !

Comment: Ok; for SHIFT + Enter you could use the AcceptReturn Property of a TextBox and set it to true. When you set Height = Auto then your Textbox is expanding everytime you push Enter or Enter + Shift and adds a line

Comment: Copieng is pretty easy with this. you only have to trigger the send and delete of the content when Enter is pushed (but not CTRL)

Answer (score 4):

The Result of the Solution is this:

Normal 
[image: Normal]

After one `SHIFT + ENTER` 
[image]

When you push `ENTER` it looks like in Normal only without text in the box

As mentioned in the comments you could use the `AcceptsReturn` and `TextWrapping` properties for a multiline textbox (like in steam).
Use `Height = Auto` for a better looking one (otherwise you only have one line and all other lines disappear) 
**XAML** 
for Textbox:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
     TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
     Width="497" AcceptsReturn="True" 
     KeyDown="TextBoxKeyDown" PreviewKeyDown="TextBoxPreviewKeyDown"/>
```

**Event Handler:** 
This is not that easy as i thought first :'D But i figured it out.
When you use the `AcceptsReturn` Property the `Enter Key` is Handeled by the `AcceptsReturn`. So if you push enter you will see a new line instead of a Send() if you programm is like this:

```
private void TextBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = sender as TextBox;
    // This will never happen because the Enter Key is handeled before
    // That means TextBoxKeyDown is not triggered for the Enter key
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter &&
        !(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)) &&
        !(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift)))
    {
        // Send(textBox.Text)
        textbox.Text = "";
    }
}
```

So you need to implement the `PreviewKeyDown` eventhandler. Because in the `PreviewKeyDown` event handler the Event is routed through the (Parent)Elements.
[Look at this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718190/if-set-to-true-acceptsreturn-disables-detection-of-key-return-in-a-multiline-te)

Also note the e.Handled = true line. Otherwise the Enter is routed through the method to the AcceptsReturn and you will have 2 lines after the enter, but the Textbox is empty.
**With this method the KeyDown Method is no longer needed!**

```
private void TextBoxPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Enter key is routed and the PreviewKeyDown is also fired with the 
    // Enter key
    var textbox = sender as TextBox;
    // You don't want to clear the box when CTRL and/or SHIFT is down
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && 
        !(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)) &&
        !(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift)))
    {
        textbox.Text = "";
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The **pros** of the Multiline Textbox is that you can copy and paste
+ you have no problems with CTRL pushed or not.

What do you think about it?

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the code. I will try it as soon as I can. But I believe creating a new line on Steam is `SHIFT + ENTER` and on Skype it's `CTRL + ENTER`, right ? Either, I don't mind, when at lease one combination is possible !

Comment: yeah i think it is always SHIFT + ENTER, but both will work :)

Comment: oh i just found out that you won't trigger the keydown event when ENTER is pushed... i will look further

Comment: should work fine now - not working for CTRL + ENTER :)

Comment: But what about the text after the cursor position ? Will it be placed after the newline ?

Comment: Alright, I tested your code but something seems wrong. If I press `ENTER`, or `right SHIFT + ENTER`, the `textbox.Text = ""`; is reached inside `TextBoxPreviewKeyDown`. But for `right SHIFT or CTRL + ENTER`, nothing happens. So in all cases, the if condition within `TextBoxKeyDown` is never called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80075/discussion-between-mackovich-and-jens-horstmann).